# Finding an $x$-intercept of a parabola from given information

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

> The parabola in the figure below has a negative intercept and a positive intercept $(a,0)$ on the $x$-axis, and the equation of the axis of symmetry at $x = 2$. What are the all possible values for the $x$-intercept $(a,0)$?
>
> [image]

I know that the equation of a parabola opening up will have the form $(x-h)^2=4p(y-k)$. Since the axis of symmetry is $x=2,$ then $x$ value of the vertex is $2$. So, $h=2$. Then $x$-intercept $(a,0)$ it is a point in the parabola. I thought to then substitute those values into the equation, but I don't know what else to do.

$(x-h)^2=4p(y-k)$

$(a-2)^2=4p(0-k)$

I have like three incognita there. I don't think I can assume that the focus is the point $(2,0)$ so I can find $p.$. I'm a bit lost here; will appreciate any help.

Comment: The most we can say is that the parabola is symmetric about x=2. So the more we shift the negative intercept towards the left, the more the positive intercept is shifted towards thr right. So the positive x-intercept grows without bound.  However, the maximum value for the left hand side intercept is 0), like, just less than 0. So the minimum value of positive intercept is (4. So $a\in(4,\infty)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By observing the graph, we can comment that $a>2$...(i)

Now, as $x=2$ is the axis of symmetry ,thus the negative intercept on the x axis is $(2-(a-2),0)=(4-a,0)$

Also,$4-a<0 $ (as it is the negative intercept )

$\implies a>4$ ...(ii)

From (i) and (ii) we can conlude that $a>4$.

Comment: Ohhh never mind. I forgot about what symmetry does. So the distance from the $x$ value in the origin to $x$ value of the symmetry axis is $2$. Then the distance from $x$ value of the origin to the positive intercept is $a$... then the distance from $x=2$ to $x=a$ is $a-2$ that is the same distance from $x=2$ to the negative $x$ intercept. Finally, to get from $x=2$ to $x$ value of the $x$ intercept in the left of the symmetry axis is $2-(a-2)=4-a$. Then because it negative we set the inequality $4-a<0$. Thanks for your help. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The parabola's left $x$-intercept, being negative, must be more than $\color{red}2$ units away from its axis of symmetry $x=\color{green}2.$

So, its right $x$-intercept must be likewise; that is, $$a>\color{green}2+\color{red}2.$$